# Not able to generate pdf with logo

Tags: php, dompdf

I'm not able to get my PDF printed if I add a logo in my `template_header.php` file.
If I enable `include_once("template_header.php")` it's not generating any PDF, and it reports this error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function imagecreatetruecolor()
```

If I disable my header (i.e. above the `include_once` line) it's generating a PDF without a logo and containing text only.

I tried enabling below, but the same problem persists:

```
define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", true);
```

My dompdf ver. is `dompdf_0-6-0_beta3`.

Can anyone help me on this?

Below is the updated code

```
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php"); 
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$html = '
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>booking</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text\css" media="screen" />

</head>
<body>

<div align="center" id="mainwrap">
<?php include_once("template_header.php")?>

</div>
</body>
</html>';
$dompdf = new DOMPDF(); 
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

Comment: Check for the gd installation in your php

Comment: @swapnesh: thanks for ur response!! What is gd install? I have php ver. 5.2 with apche

Comment: please find my screenshot added in answer and let me know the case then

Comment: hey sidd can you post your code ..........

Comment: @venkat, below is the code. require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php"); 
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$html = ' ---HTML/PHP CODE --</html>';
$dompdf = new DOMPDF(); 
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample1.pdf");

Comment: can you post it in your question and do one more thing where you want to put logo..tell where it is in your directory

Answer (score 3):

Please check your GD library installation in php.

Run `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in a php file and check for GD library then

[image]

Update -

Check your `php.ini` and look for `extension=php_gd2.dll`

If `;` [commented] then un comment it and restart the services then.

Comment: @ swpnesh, its not shwing any GD library info. Also ;gd.jpeg_ignore_warning = 0 is disabled in my php.ini. Do i need to enable it?

Comment: @sidd yes to resolve the above problem you need to enable the GD library extension in your PHP

Comment: @swpnesh, sorry but do not have extension=php_gd2.dll in my php.ini. Further could search only ;gd.jpeg_ignore_warning = 0 containing gd as name.

Comment: @sidd if might be a case as I am having  a different php version than urs...just search for gd and u will get urs for sure

Comment: thanks yes i will search it once. Actually i tried enabling line 'gd.jpeg_ignore_warning = 0' but stil isuue is persisting,

Comment: @sidd also restart the services once done to reflect the change

Comment: tried, but still same issue!! Just to add on, I'm able to print the text in coloured also, but just the logo not able to print

Comment: same error PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function imagecreatetruecolor()

Comment: @sidd The overall advice here is correct. You need to enable GD. Are you installing PHP directly or using something like XAMP?

Comment: @BrianS I suggested him that already..but he left the conversation in middle lol :)

Comment: @brian: no its not xamp, using apache 2.0.64, php 5.2.10 on win xp machine

Comment: @sidd So installed using a PHP installer or archived download? PHP on windows includes GD, but I can't remember if it's enabled by default. If you are using an installer then re-run it and modify your PHP installation to include GD.